# How can I write test cases without knowing the application in Selenium IDE?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium

If I don't know the application I only know the Software requirements, on Software requirement basis I need to write the test cases in Selenium IDE. So how can I write the Test cases on Software requirement basis?
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you have access to the application? I mean a running test version deployed on a webserver?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Your can write the test conditions, and to some extend the test specification. But the test implementation depends on the implementation of the HTML, since no concrete interface seems to be given.
http://www.software-tester.ch/PDF-Files/istqb_glossary_of_testing_terms_2.2.pdf

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how good the software requirements are written. If there are mock ups with clear process flow of the application you can try to write the tests getting the ID's of the objects you'll be interacting with from a file or excel sheet.

Of course it's not normal / advisable  to do that, but there's always a way...

Comment: Agreed, in case of a detailed technical specification. But that wouldn't be about the quality of the requirements, but their abstraction level. And then you're close to an implementation ...

Comment: Well, I would be really surprised if APIs are detailed upfront in specification. Usually, API definition is an iterative process. And... if we're talking about frontend structure, that's even more a subject change.

Comment: This would be impossible in my company, that's for sure :D
Anyway, is this guy multiplying questions or something? 
http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/8078/how-to-write-test-cases-in-selenium-webdriver-using-c-simultaneously-when-web